# How to convert datetime in 2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00 format?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

In laravel 8 app making request to mailchimp I recieve string datatime in format

```
2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00
```

Which format is it? I can parse it manually, but are there better way to convert it with
carbon(or other tool) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the ISO-8601 format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 it's actually pretty common. The same will be valid in most languages. The native `DateTime` class of PHP supports it:

```php
$moment = new DateTime('2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00');
```

So do `Carbon` (and all other PHP stuff like `strtotime` and date-time related libraries):

```php
$moment = new Carbon('2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00');
$moment = Carbon::parse('2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert it to carbon instance using `c` format

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('c','2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00');
```

And if you want to convert any carbon instance to *ISO 8601*, you can use

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('c');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format your time string using `Carbon`:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00')->toDateTimeString();

Output: "2021-05-24 04:44:56"
```

And also using using `strtotime`:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00")) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a local timestring representation. You can 'nicely format' it quite easily with [`carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
Carbon::parse('2021-05-24T04:44:56+00:00')->toDateTimeString();
```

The above will output:

```
2021-05-24 04:44:56
```

There are plenty other formatters available or you can define your own.